# Update Cocos2d to 2.0

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I tried to update to a cocos2d game (it was not me who did the beginning), I followed the tutorial (Option A: By updating your old project) from this [link](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3amigrate_to_v2.0).

but when I run the project give me an error of libraries

Lexical or Processor Issue
   'kazmath / kazmath.h' file not found

Comment: drag libs folder to header search path and make it recursive.

Comment: already added in the build settings in the headers search path. how I get to be recursive?

Comment: I try but don't work. thanks for help

Comment: strange! At least try this "Your_Project_folder/libs/kazmath/include"

Comment: I experienced a difficult time when I tried to go from 1.x to 2.0 as well. Honestly, it was much easier for me to just create a new project using cocos2d 2.0 from the start and just drag my project files into the new workspace. Not an ideal solution, but actually took much less time than trying to sort through all the errors. I did have to update bits of cocos2d code, but that wasn't too bad.